# Create, get and edit user information in same form and template

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I'm trying to retrieve data from user. The form where i want to show the user information is also the same that i use to update this information.

## Update3

After some updates I make this work and this is my code. If somenone have a better way to do this can share it :)

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
# Create your models here.
class informacionFacturacion(models.Model):
    usuario = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    apellidos = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    nombres = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    [More fields...]
    def __str__(self):
        self.apellidos
```

**forms.py**

```
from .models import informacionFacturacion
#Create your forms here.
class informacionFacturacionForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = informacionFacturacion
        fields = [
            "usuario",
            "apellidos",
            "nombres",
            [More fields...]
        ]
```

**views.py**

```
@login_required
def datosPersonales(request):
    #Filter query by user ID
    query = informacionFacturacion.objects.filter(usuario=request.user)

    form = informacionFacturacionForm()
    #If query has content, edit record, else, create a new record
    if query:
        if request.method == "POST":
            form = informacionFacturacionForm(request.POST or None, instance=query[0])
            if form.is_valid():
                edit_content = form.save()
                edit_content.save()

    else:
        if request.method == "POST":
            form = informacionFacturacionForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                create_content = form.save(commit=False)
                create_content.save()
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('datosPersonales'))

    context = {
        "titulo": "Datos personales | Co.",
        "body_class": "class= sidebar_main_open sidebar_main_swipe",
        "form": form,
        "infoFacturacion": query,
    }
    template = "micuenta/datosPersonales.html"
    return render(request, template, context)
```

Thanks for the support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first glance, it seems that the `informacionFacturacion` table is not being populated. Have you checked that the `instance.save()` is reached? (in other words, that the form is valid)

Second, in the template you want to use the `informacionFacturacion` object as the form elements, and you are handling them separately. Do:

```
if request.POST:
    form = informacionFacturacionForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        instance.save()
    else:
        # handle here the form error's, maybe report it in the template
else:
    query = informacionFacturacion.objects.filter(usuario=request.user)
    form = informacionFacturacionForm(instance=query[0])
```

and render the `form` parameter insead of `infoFacturacion`:

```
{{ form.as_p }}
```

finally, make sure that your template form id's matches the form element names, otherwise the form won't be filled.

**UPDATE**

Based on your edit, now the error is in this line:

```
form = informacionFacturacionForm(request.POST, instance=query_id)
```

`query_id` is an `int`, and it is expecting a model. Change the following line:

```
query_id = informacionFacturacion.objects.get(usuario=request.user).id
```

to

```
query = informacionFacturacion.objects.get(usuario=request.user)
```

and the faulty line to:

```
form = informacionFacturacionForm(request.POST, instance=query)
```

that should work for now, although code can be simplified a lot.

**EDIT 2**

Here is what I assume you want:

```
@login_required
def datosPersonales(request):
    query = informacionFacturacion.objects.filter(usuario=request.user)

    if request.method == "POST":  # This will handle the template form's POST
        form = informacionFacturacionForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            asd = form.save(commit=False)
            asd.save()
            # Here you may want to redirect to somewhere else
    # Im not sure here, I guess that you want to handle the GET method if 
    # there is no form in the request. Post your template form to see what
    # is happening.
    else:
        form = informacionFacturacionForm(instance=query)
        # you dont need to save it, it is already in DB

    context = {
        "titulo": "Datos personales | Co.",
        "body_class": "class= sidebar_main_open sidebar_main_swipe",
        # I think here is your main issue, you are handling a form object
        # AND a infoFacturacion object. You need to use just the
        # form object in the template and render it accordingly.
        "form": form,   
        "infoFacturacion": query, 
    }
    template = "micuenta/datosPersonales.html"
    return render(request, template, context)
```

Comment: I've realized that I cannot edit the content using save (). I will write an if statement to check if the table have content. I can do that with: if infoFacturacion: #show edit form else: #show create form.  Right?

Comment: what do you mean by "edit the content"? The object form and the form in the template are both modifiable. If you want to see what comes from the template you can use `print request.POST` It will print a dictionary with the elements of the form(s) sent in the POST method of the view.

Comment: What I'm trying to do here is to show the table content in the same view and form where can be edited. I will try some code now and I will update the post.

Comment: I've updated my question. I can see the form to save and edit data in the same view, now im getting an error when i want to update. It's in the question..  :)

Comment: If I change "query" to informacionFacturacion.objects.get() I get this error "informacionFacturacion' is not iterable. And if I print in terminal when change query_id to informacionFacturacion.objects.get (usuario=request.user) I get the returned self.apellidos from model.

Comment: OK. Please note that `get()` method returns a single model, while `filter()` returns a list of models (a QuerySet actually, but can be iterated as a list). So if you use `get()` you have to remove the `[0]` from the query object, since it is already a `informacionFacturacion` model and not an iterable. 

Second, if you see `self.apellidos` in terminal is because internally the `__str__` method of `informacionFacturacion` is called. I will re-edit my answer with a more detailed code, but keep in mind that I'm not able to run it, thus type errors might occur.

Comment: Finally works. I will update my functional code in shortly. Thanks a lot for your support. I modified a bit the last update u did, cause with your code i was able to create new content, but cannot be edited. Best Regards!

Answer (score 0):

Well, I was with the same problem on my sytem, so I made this solution, maybe it works to you! =D

I'm changing the value of the submit button and using the same form:

```
<button type="submit" id="submitButton" name="button" value="">Save</button>
```

If is a new task, I change the value of the button with JQuery:

```
$('#submitButton').val('new');
```

And if is an edition, I change the value again:

```
$('#submitButton').val('edit');
```

On my views.py, I check if is an edit or a new save by the value of the button:

```
def index(request):
tasks = Task.object.filter()
context = {
    'tasks': tasks
}
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = NewTask(request.POST or None)
    if request.POST['button'] == 'new':
        if form.is_valid():
            context['is_valid'] = True
            form.save()
            form = NewTask()
        else:
            context['is_valid'] = False

    if request.POST['button'] == 'edit':
        instance = Task.object.filter(pk=request.POST['id']).first()
        form = NewTask(request.POST, instance=instance)
        if form.is_valid():
            context['is_valid'] = True
            form.save()
        else:
            context['is_valid'] = False
else:
    form = NewTask()

context['form'] = form
return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```